# A mysterious telephone message

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, language

You arrive home after an exhausting day.  Tossing your bag in a corner of the room, you greet your roommate, who is lounging on the sofa playing a video game.

"Any messages?" you ask.

"Just one," he replies.  "I answered the phone and the person on the end just started spouting gobbledegook.  I wasn't sure if it was important, so I tried writing it down as best I could, but it made no sense at all."  He gestures toward a notepad next to the telephone.

You pick up the paper and read the message he's written:

> Gem a pellet one A just week elk urn key con S eight own Amelia vent on seal view played a Monday Louie dumb apple ay O seat oak a pass E blah detail we duh mutt allophone neigh as ankh sank dew eat wheat D snuff say rosy set mares see.

You stare at the paper in perplexity for a few minutes, and then suddenly it begins to make sense.  A big grin begins to form on your face.  You quickly jot some numbers on the pad, and pick up the phone.

***What did the note say?***
***Who are you phoning?***

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The note is

> An English phonetic rendering of French

and it *really* says

> Je m'appelle Antoine et je suis quelqu'un qui connaissait ton ami il y a vingt ans. S'il vous plait demandez lui de m'appeler aussitot que possible. Dites à lui de me téléphoné à 552-881-9067, merci. (Thank you [M Oehm](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9860/m-oehm) and [Anton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22184/anton) and [Business Cat](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/22168/business-cat))
>
>   Incidentally, all the message is saying is that your friend Antoine of 20 years is calling and would like to be called back as soon as possible.
>
>   ***Sacre bleu!***

Comment: D snuff = dix-neuf ie 19

Comment: For the record, @MOehm, I appreciated it. Anton helped me in the chat as well.

Comment: I originally intended to make the name as you have it, but then somehow ended up making it "Etoine" instead, which isn't a real name.  The "dix neuf" was just oversight on my part -- not thinking too closely about it that 10 is not a single-digit number.

Comment: Also, note that assuming he's calling from France, the number would typically be listed in pairs of digits.

Comment: @gentlepurplerain if I overwrote your edit (I'm on mobile at the moment, hard to tell) feel free to fix anything

Comment: Shouldn't you include the English equivalent of whatever this means in the answer?

Comment: @ffao lol whoops, it's in there now